# Get number of online users from public website page

Tags: javascript

Say there is a website homepage that publicly displays stats like online users, page generation time, etc.
Is it possible to retrieve those specific values and display them on a piece of software, like for example a simple charting extension written in Javascript? Or does it depend on the software used to get them?

Just to be clear, I'm asking about a generic public webpage, not about my own website - i.e. I do not have any access to internal phps, codes, variables, etc. of the website/domain.

Comment: This is called _web scraping_. You won't be able to do it in Javascript because of the same-domain restriction, but you can do it in a server script.

Comment: Yes, you'd need your own server proxy. Although maybe there's some service to make it easier. https://www.kimonolabs.com/ (I've never used it myself, but it looks cool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method which you are looking for is web scraping. Basically it's the process of getting the required data which is already shown in that webpage. You can find tons of tutorial regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The server is the only thing that knows how many people are browsing. This is not obtainable from the front end unless the back end is providing it to you.

Comment: The server displays it on its web page, so anyone who can access the web page can get it.

Comment: @Barmar He mentioned that "unless the back end is providing it to you"

Comment: And the question says that it is. _publicly displays stats like online users_.